# How to exclude an included profile in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in `application.yml` I added `spring.profiles.include: auth` since the app will be deployed in DEV, UT, PROD environments, so `application-auth.yml` will take effect in these environments.

But when I debug the app locally, there is no need to enable auth-related features,

May I ask how to exclude the `auth` profile in `application-local.yml`?

Thanks a lot!

---

update:

I know Spring has `spring.profiles.active`, but here the profile `auth` must be included by `spring.profiles.include`.

Is there any other way based on this premise?

Thanks.

Comment: start the application locale with active profile local, as parameter on the starting command. like -Dspring.profiles.active=local

Comment: Hi @ΣωτήρηςΡαφαήλ 
the profile `auth` needs to be included by `spring.profiles.include`, is there any solution then?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare all active profiles locally by adding the environment variable

> SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=localhost

This way you are only activating the profile of `localhost` for example.

Example in intellij:
[Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2pPi.png)

Comment: many thanks! but the final result is the 2 profiles are both active: `2023-12-21 23:49:32.546  INFO 22080 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.SpringBootDemoApplication          : The following 2 profiles are active: "auth", "localhost"`